# Exception during connecting to postgresql database using wt c++ library?

Tags: c++, database, postgresql, wt

I`m trying to connect to postgresql database which name is "galaxydatabase" and I encountered an unhandled exception. 
Source code:

```
#include <Wt/Dbo/Dbo>
#include <Wt/Dbo/backend/Postgres>

namespace dbo = Wt::Dbo;

void run()
{
    dbo::backend::Postgres po;
    po.connect("galaxydatabase");
    // or
    //dbo::backend::Postgres po("galaxydatabase"); // the same exception???
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    run();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which is the exact exception you receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`connect()`](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1Dbo_1_1backend_1_1Postgres.html#a003ae8b797aea816669d4f02a34c6806) expects a PostgreSQL connection string, e.g. `"host=127.0.0.1 user=test password=test port=5432 dbname=test"`. You can provide different parameters as needed, leave out what is not needed.

[The PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) has more on what parameters are allowed and what they do.